# How to Fetch and Filter Data from WordPress API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, carousel

I'm building a Flutter app that fetches data from a WordPress site using its API. The app has a menu with different categories, and when a user taps on a category in the menu, I want to fetch only the data related to that particular category and display it on the home page by filtering the cards based on the category.

I've already implemented the menu and fetching data from WordPress using the WordPressPosts().getPostsByCategory(categoryId) method. However, I'm not sure how to filter the fetched data and pass it to the home page to show only the selected category's posts.

I have a CardsWidget that displays cards based on the selectedCategories list, which I'm currently updating with the fetched categories. Here's the code snippet:

In MenuState :

```
    class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
    GlobalKey<CardsWidgetState> _myKey = GlobalKey<CardsWidgetState>();
```

In MenuState onTap of menu list:

```
onTap: () {
         Menu.isMenuItemTapped=true;
         setState(() {
         _myKey.currentState?.fetchData();
          });
         widget.toggleMenu(); // Close the menu
     }
```

In CardsWidgetState:

```
    void fetchDataByCategoryId(int? id, String categoryName) async {
        print("############");
        List<dynamic>posts=[];
        List<dynamic> fetchedPostsById =
        await WordPressPosts().getPostsByCategory(id!);
    
       // setState(() {
          posts = fetchedPostsById;
        //});
        for (var post in posts) {
          if (post['title'] != null &&
              post['title']['rendered'] != null &&
              post['excerpt'] != null &&
              post['excerpt']['rendered'] != null &&
              post['_embedded'] != null &&
              post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'] != null &&
              post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['source_url'] != null) {
            String title = post['title']['rendered'];
            String description = _parseHtmlString(post['content']['rendered']);
    
            final text = "${post['content']['rendered']}";
            RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+');
            Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(text);
    
            List<String> localVideoUrl = [];
            List<int> videoUrlIndices = []; // List to store the indices of video URLs
    
            matches.forEach((match) {
              final video = text.substring(match.start, match.end);
              if (video.contains("mp4")) {
                localVideoUrl.add(video);
                videoUrlIndices.add(match.start); // Add the index of the video URL to the list
                print('Video URL: $video, Index: ${match.start}');
              }
            });
    
            if (localVideoUrl.isNotEmpty) {
              localVideoUrl.forEach((video) {
                CardWidget.videoUrl.add(video);
              });
            }
    
            // Add the localVideoUrl to the videoUrl list in _CardsWidgetState
            CardWidget.videoUrl.addAll(localVideoUrl);
    
            String imageUrl = post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['source_url'];
            bool isHighlighted = false; // Set your logic for highlighting here
            //Color color = Colors.white; // Set your desired color here
            String categoryText =categoryName;
            Color tabColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired tab color here
            Color tabTextColor = ColorConst.menuItemBorder; // Set your desired tab text color here
            Color color = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Default color
            Color descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBorder; // Default description color
    
            // Assign colors based on category
            if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'global') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor1;
              tabTextColor =  ColorConst.cardcolor1;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'markets') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor2;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.cardcolor2;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'products') {
              color = ColorConst.red;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.red;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'portfolios') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor3;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.cardcolor3;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBorder; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'trending') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor4;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.cardcolor4;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBorder; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'uncategorized') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor5;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.cardcolor5;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired color here
            } else if (categoryText.toLowerCase() == 'economy') {
              color = ColorConst.cardcolor6;
              tabTextColor = ColorConst.cardcolor6;
              descriptionColor = ColorConst.menuItemBackground; // Set your desired color here
            }
    
            CardWidget card = CardWidget(
              title: title,
              description: description,
              imageUrl: imageUrl,
              isHighlighted: isHighlighted,
              color: color,
              tabText: categoryText,
              tabColor: tabColor,
              tabTextColor: tabTextColor,
              descriptionColor: descriptionColor,
              isVideo: localVideoUrl.isNotEmpty,
              index: localVideoUrl.isNotEmpty ? CardWidget.videoUrl.indexOf(localVideoUrl[CardsWidget.cardindex]) : -1,
            );
    
            setState(() {
              cards.clear();
              cards.add(card);
              //CardWidget.videoUrlIndex= CardWidget.videoUrl.indexOf(localVideoUrl[CardsWidget.cardindex]);
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

I'm unsure how to pass the data back to the home page to update the CardsWidget accordingly.

Could anyone guide me on how to properly filter the fetched data based on the selected category and update the CardsWidget on the home page with the filtered data?

Thanks in advance! Let me know if you need any additional information.